# System.IO.StreamReader returns corrupted output

Tags: vb.net

The below given code  is returning corrupted data to the variable 'mystr' 
like

PK     ! ��fѲ  �   [Content_Types].xml �(�      �UMk�@���^��N%�9�ɱ

It was reading the word files correctly. Suddenly it started happening without any change in code or software versions or source files!!  Any word file I try to run through the below code gives the same corrupted output. I'm able to open the file in MsWord without any issue.

```
        Dim myStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim myStr As String
        myStreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("c:\test.docx")
        myStr = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        myStreamReader.Close()
```

Any suggestions why it is happening ?

Comment: You cannot read binary data, like a .docx file, with StreamReader.  It is a compressed archive, PK was Phil Katz, the inventor of the ZIP file format.  Reading .docx files requires Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word or the OpenXML SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You can't read a Word document using the `StreamReader` class as the file itself isn't plain text (it contains the data you find 'corrupted').

[This](http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-parse-the-text-content-from-microsoft-word-document/) link will help you reading text from a Word document.